# Managing 2 network interfaces

Tags: networking, server, interface

I have a raspberry pi, where eth0 is directly connected to my laptop for the purpose of ssh. I get an internet either through wlan0 or usb0 (tethering), however when both eth0 and wlan0/usb0 are connected, I receive no internet while I can connect to pi through ssh. (When I ping www.google.com, it is not reachable)

If I unplug eth0 and with reboot, I receive connection from wlan0/usb0.

Is there anyways to configure so that I get ssh through eth0, while receive internet from wlan0/usb0?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=215140&p=1324060#p1324060

Changing metric of eth0 to give less priority over usb0 and wlan0 worked for me.